# is it good to use Laptop keyboard cover and body cover?

Tags: mac, laptop, macbook, temperature

Currently I'm using a laptop keyboard cover (for a Mac); my brother told me that it's not good for your laptop, because it keeps the laptop heat inside. Is this true?

[image]

I'm also using the [Laptop Plastic Cover](http://www.speckproducts.com/products/seethru/macbook-pro-15-aluminum-black-keys/160) - would this have any effect on the laptop heat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used a MacBook, however, I would think most of the heat comes out of the back with the fans and heatsinks. I wouldn't think that the cover would keep heat from escaping, since it's just a thin plastic sheet. I don't think that it would really make your laptop much hotter.

As for the plastic cover, as long as all of the intake fans are uncovered it should be fine to use. The hard plastic that protects the LCD should definitely be fine.

Comment: While I agree fully with your conclusions, I feel the need to point out that the thickness of the plastic is almost completely irrelevant to how well it insulates. One must keep in mind that the major mechanism of heat transfer in this case is convection, not conduction, and thus the lack of holes in the sheet has greater influence than any thickness.

Answer (score 1):

I used to use an [iSkin](http://www.iskin.com/protouch_apple_keyboard/) cover for my MacBook. I never had any issues with it. However, I didn't use it for long as it drastically reduced my typing speed.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using keyboard cover for a year, and has no issues with heat.
Yes, the issues were more on the reduced typing speed because of the silicone cover, until very recently when I found a replacement which is thinner yet sturdy. Happy! The brand is --somehow they name it-- "BLINK". If you happen to be in Jakarta-Indonesia, it might worth to seek for this one. Damage? Not much, about USD 15.